# How to know an application is run as administrator, if it doesn't show that in its title bar?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, administrator

Using "troubleshoot compatibility" I have configured many applications to always run as administrator. Visual Studio, SQL Server and many more applications show that in their title bar using a `(Administrator)` indicator.

However, recently I had to configure Android Studio to always run as administrator. But it doesn't indicate anything in the title bar.

Now how can I make sure that it's run as administrator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't force an application to display this in the title bar.

Open `Task Manager`, change to the `Details` tab.

Right click on a column header and click `Select columns...`, scroll down to the end of the list and select `Elevated`.

Now you can see which user processes are running as elevated administrator.

Many system process don't display anything in that column, you have to elevate task manager itself to see their status.

There are other tools like Process Explorer which display more detailed information, but you have to download these first.